# postgresql, generated fields from jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, create-table, jsonb

I'm using a generated column with postgresql 12 with data from a jsonb field (containing a json with `"public":true` or `"public":false`

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    ...,
    data jsonb,
    public boolean generated always as ((data ->> 'public')::boolean) stored,
    ...
)
```

sometimes the json (coming from different applications) is missing the **public** key. how i can set a default to FALSE to public column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) returns `NULL` when the key is not found, so you can just [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) that to the desired default value:

```
COALESCE((data ->> 'public')::boolean, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression along with the `?` operator, like:

```
create table people (
    ...,
    data jsonb,
    public boolean generated always as (
        case 
            when data ? 'public' then (data ->> 'public')::boolean
            else false
        end
    ) stored
);
```